# jqplot completely redraw a graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

How do I completely destroy a graph and then redraw one from scratch.  The reason I need this is because I want to have the option of changing the graph type from let's say a bar graph to a line graph.

I don't think you can do that strait up, so instead I try to destroy the graph completely and just make a new one.

```
plot.destroy();
$.jqplot("graph_id", [data], options);
```

The destroying went fine, but the reinit did not work at all.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get an error?  Works for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/jAHYc/2/

Comment: Yea sorry, I just found out that it was my own error. It works fine now :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my own error, the jqplot worked just fine actually.

Answer (score 2):

Do like the following,

```
var inti = new Array();
inti.push([0, 0, 0]);
var plot2 = $.jqplot('graph_id', inti, null);
plot2.destroy();
plot2 =$.jqplot("graph_id", [data], options);
```

this will redraw ur jqplot..